# Pythonic way to find duplicate objects in a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tons of location points with several attributes like `time_stamp`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `accuracy`, `velocity` etc. Now I want to remove duplicate location points on these conditions:

1. Latitude is same
2. Longitude is same
3. Month is same
4. Day is same

The other attributes dont matter at all for comparison. My strategy is to modify `__hash__`, `__eq__` and `__ne__` methods to include the above conditions and feed them into `set` function to remove the duplicates.

```
item1 = Location(1510213074679, 286220203, 772454413, 1414, None, None, None, 78, None)
item2 = Location(1510213074679, 286220203, 772454413, 5, 6, 80, 226, None, None)
item3 = Location(1523620644975, 286265651, 772427842, 65, None, None, 193, 10, None)

x = set()
x.add(item1)
x.add(item2)
x.add(item3)
print(x)
{<__main__.Location at 0x7fd725559eb8>, <__main__.Location at 0x7fd725604dd8>}
```

Length of set is as expected i.e 2 (two elements with same attributes).

The result which I expect, can be obtained as follows

```
[f.data() for f in x]
```

Is there any other pythonic way to achieve the same result?

```py
class Location(object):
    def __init__(self, time_stamp, latitude, longitude, accuracy, velocity,
                 heading, altitude, vertical_accuracy, activity):
        self.time_stamp = float(time_stamp) / 1000
        self.latitude = float(latitude) / 10000000
        self.longitude = float(longitude) / 10000000
        self.accuracy = accuracy
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.heading = heading
        self.altitude = altitude
        self.vertical_accuracy = vertical_accuracy
        self.activity = activity

        self.timestamp, self.year, self.month = month_aware_time_stamp(
            self.time_stamp)
        self.hash = self.hashed()

    def data(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def hashed(self):
        string = str(self.latitude) + str(self.longitude)
        return hashlib.sha3_224(string.encode()).hexdigest()

    def __hash__(self):
        string = str(self.latitude) + str(self.longitude)
        return hash(string.encode())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Override the default Equals behavior"""
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.hash == other.hash and self.month == other.month and self.year == other.year
        return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        """Override the default Unequal behavior"""
        return self.hash != other.hash or self.month != other.month or self.year != other.year
```

Comment: Where are your data coming from? Is the `Location` object used for any other purpose in your code, or is it solely for deduplication?

Comment: The data is in JSON file,  each JSON will have more than 100000 entries.  My task at hand is to find the most visited locations in a month of a year.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `hash`

Since tuples are hashable if their elements are hashable, you can just do

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.latitude, self.longitude, self.year, self.month))
```

If you want to have locations that are near each other be set as the same, you might have to round the coordinates

## `repr`

for debugging, adding a repr can be handy:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return (
        "Position("
        f"lat: {self.latitude}, "
        f"lon: {self.longitude}, "
        f"year: {self.year}, "
        f"month: {self.month}, "
        ")"
    )
```

## Counting

To count, you can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and just feed it an iterable of Positions.

```
counter = Counter(locations)
most_visited = counter.most_common(<n>)
```

You will need one Counter per year/month, but this can be done with a `defaultdict(Counter)`

Comment: I exactly did it like this,  rounding off latitude and longitude to three decimal places,  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First - you are expected to provide complete and working code. To fully understand your code `month_aware_time_stamp` is missing (I'll try to guess what it probably returns).

Second - I think your approach and your class `Location` is broken by design. Also the implementation is a mess but let's stick to the design first. What your class does

```
>>> item1 = Location(1510213074679, 286220203, 772454413, 1414, None, None, None, 78, None)
>>> item2 = Location(1510213074679, 286220203, 772454413, 5, 6, 80, 226, None, None)
>>> item1 == item2
True
```

This is weird behavior. Nobody would expect that. Your code is not maintainable and will cause surprising behavior when being maintained.

- If you do not need all the other attributes - do not store them at all. Just store the attributes you want to compare and do your stuff without strange hash implementations
- If you need all that attributes in your class, then your implementation will render the class useless for any other use. Do not overwrite the comparison behavior but either extract the relevant data to a second data structure (tuple, ...) or provide an external comparison function for calling functions like `sort()`. You can always do comprehension to extract relevant attributes to a tuple

.

```
some_set = {(s.latitude, s.longitude, s.year, s.month) for s in x}
```

or you immediately count with `collections.Counter`

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter((s.latitude, s.longitude, s.year, s.month) for s in x)
```

I will skip the review of the concrete implementetion as the design has to change. But

- never implement some homebrew hash if the builtin `hash()` is sufficient.
- if you think you have to implement `__hash__()` and/or `**eq**() please follow the guidelines in [[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__])
- never keep hash values unless you can guarantee consistency

Comment: I have changed my code, never keep hash values unless you can guarantee consistency but couldnt understand your statement , Thanks.